# How to display date in edittext and update it via datepicker using BindingAdapter and android Mvvm

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-datepicker, android-mvvm

I have a `button` and `editTtext` i want to set today's date into edittext then the user can set the new date using the button and display the `datepicker` to select a new one. The problem I couldn't set the current date in `edittext` I can displayed `datepicker` and the selection. I used `BindingAdapter` and `MVVM` I'm new to this approach any guide or help thanks in advance.

**BindingAdapter:**

```
@BindingAdapter("selectDate")
fun bindDateClicks(button: Button,mutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<String>) {
    button.setOnClickListener {
        selectDate(button.context,mutableLiveData)
    }
}

fun selectDate(context: Context,mutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<String>) {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)


    val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(context,
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
                view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            mutableLiveData.value = year.toString() + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth.toString()
        },year,month,day)
    datePickerDialog.show()

}
```

**button:**

```
 <Button
                android:text="set Date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:selectDate="@{viewModel.currentDate}"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner3"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.005"/>
```

**viewmodel:**

```
val currentDate = MutableLiveData<String>()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create live data or observable field for a date into ViewModel (Initially assign default date).

Date picker dialog should be activity or fragment level.
When date change form date picker, update date into ViewModel. Define Viewmodel into you layout files.

Comment: This link (in spanish) may help with 'Date picker dialog should be activity or fragment level ...' https://programacionymas.com/blog/como-pedir-fecha-android-usando-date-picker

Comment: Thank you for the solution shown in the blog. Even without knowing Spanish it is very useful source of information on how to establish relation between a fragment and a date picker in Kotlin and Java

Answer (score 1):

First of all,
Dialog should be part of activity/fragment.

Thinking of that, you do not really need to have adapter for that.
Thinking of databinding - you might want to use separate fragment to have datepicker within it. In this case you can have shared ViewModel to share date value.

Please note, in custom binding adapter you can work with `String` instead of `LiveData<String>`

Comment: I tried to place it in my fragment and I faced context issue

Comment: What issue? Can you provide more details

Comment: I used Androidviewmodel to use context but when I placed context into the dialog couldn't be resolved